# Moving circular disk between two parallel sinusoidal curves

Tags: analysis, metric-geometry, euclidean-geometry

Find the largest radius of the circle that can be "rolled" between the curves $y = sin(x)$ and $y = sin(x)+1$.

After two weeks of research, I finally give up.

[image: circle rolling on two parallel sinusoidal curves]

Comment: Geometric intuition suggests that the optimal radius can be obtained by fitting a disc of as large radius as possible centered at the point $(0,\frac12)$. This leads to an equation that can probably easily be shown to have a unique solution, but I see no reason to expect that there would be a closed form solution. What exactly is your question? Do you want to prove that the optimal disc can be found by the method I described? Do you want estimates for the optimal radius if there is no explicit expression for it?

Comment: So you are asking for the distance between these two curves? Certainly, a segment of minimum distance would be perpendicular to both curves. You will have some fairly ugly equation, which would likely to be solvable numerically.

Comment: This strikes me as an exercise in second year multivariable calculus.  I mentally compute a relevant critical point for the function being the square of the distance between two curves to confirm Joonas's geometric intuition: the distance squared is (1 + 2sin t)^2(1 + cos^2 t) for t satisfying (1+2 Sin t) + 2t =0.

Comment: Sorry, the last constraint should be (1+ 2 sin t)cos t  + 2t = 0.  I think it's right now.

Answer (score 0):

The diameter $d$ of the largest circle is given by the minimum distance between the curves, that is
$$d=\min_{x,y}\ \sqrt{ (y-x)^2 + (1+\sin(y)-\sin(x))^2} = \sqrt{\min_{u,v}\ 4u^2 + (1+2\sin(u)\cos(v))^2},$$
where $u=\frac{y-x}{2}$, $v=\frac{y+x}{2}$. Notice that any pair of $u,v$ uniquely defines $x,y$ (and vice verse) and thus we can minimize over $u,v$ instead of $x,y$. So, we have
$$d^2 = \min_{u,v}\ 4u^2 + (1+2\sin(u)\cos(v))^2 = \min_u\ \left(4u^2 + \min_v\ (1+2\sin(u)\cos(v))^2\right).$$

Without loss of generality, we assume that $\sin(u)\geq 0$. We split minimization over $u$ into two cases:
$$\min_{u} \ldots = \min\left\{ \min_{u,\ \sin(u)\geq \frac{1}{2}} \ldots, \min_{u,\ \sin(u)< \frac{1}{2}} \ldots\right\}.$$

**Case 1:** $\sin(u)\geq \frac{1}{2}$. Then by taking an appropriate $v$, we can make $(1+2\sin(u)\cos(v))^2=0$. Furthermore, $\sin(u)\geq \frac{1}{2}$ implies $|u|\geq \frac{\pi}{6}$. Thus, the minimum value for $d$ in this case is $\frac{\pi}{3}$.

**Case 2:** $\sin(u)<\frac{1}{2}$. To minimize the $(1+2\sin(u)\cos(v))^2$ in this case, we need to take $v$ such that $\cos(v)=-1$. Therefore, we need to compute
$$\min_u 4u^2+(1-2\sin(u))^2.$$
It is clear that this minimum does not exceed 1 and we can restrict $u$ to the interval $[0,\frac{1}{2}]$. The minimum is attained at the zero of the derivative $8u-4(1-2\sin(u))\cos(u)$, which is $u\approx 0.24737$, and gives the diameter $d \approx 0.71075$.

Clearly, case 2 delivers a smaller value and thus the largest diameter is $d \approx 0.71075$.

Comment: I am a little suspicious of the conclusion of case 1.  pi > 3, right?

Comment: @TheMaskedAvenger: This simply means that case 1 does not deliver the absolute minimum. And $\frac{\pi}{3}$ is not the distance between two curves. The case 2 confirms that.

Comment: Perhaps, but the wording suggests to me that you have found a way to put a circle of diameter pi/3 in the picture between the two curves.  My take always found a circle of diameter at most 1.

Comment: @TheMaskedAvenger: I did not say that I can fit such a circle, but rather that this case implies a certain lower bound for $d$. This lower bound is not the absolute minimum however.

Comment: `The diameter  of the largest circle is given by the minimum distance between the curves` 
@Max Alekseyev
Could you elaborate more on this assumption? I feel like it is untrue.

Comment: @MarcinCharęziński: Let $D$ be the minimum distance between the curves. My claim $d=D$ splits into two inequalities: $d\leq D$ and $d\geq D$ -- which one you are concerned about?